# Django как получить от пользователя дополнительные данные?

Tags: python, django

Делаю первый проект на джанго - сервис одноразовых зашифрованных записок.  (по аналогии privatenote)
Создав записку, пользователь получает ссылку вида mysite.com/<id_записки>/<ключ_расшифровки>
Данные из get запроса отправляются во вьюху > расшифровка, вывод записки На этом этапе всё работает

вторым шагом я добавил возможность ввода пароля для дополнительного шифрования.
Сложность возникает при открытии такой записки:
Если записка с паролем (о чем есть пометка в БД) я показываю пользователю страницу с формой ввода пароля...
Паролоь я получаю через POST, но не понимаю, как сохранить и передать в функцию расшифровки (функция show_private_note) все предыдущие данные + пароль?

```
def open_private_note(request, short_id, key):
    """ find, decrypt and show note """
    if PrivateNotes.objects.filter(pk=short_id).exists():
        object_note = PrivateNotes.objects.get(pk=short_id)
        # check if note has a second password
        if object_note.is_password:
            messages.warning(request, 'Записка зашифрована дополнительным паролем!')
            return render(request, 'private_notes/input_second_password.html')
        # далее функция открытия и расшифровки
        return show_private_note(request, object_note, key, second_password=None)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Записка не найдена!')
        return render(request, 'private_notes/new_private_note.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл. Я использовал кэш джанго

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

Добавляем в кэш

```
cache.set('Тут ключ', 'Тут значение')
```

Берём значения из кэша и чистим его

```
cache.get('Тут ключ')
cache.delete('Тут ключ')
```

Работает, но мне кажется должен быть другой путь, учитывая что это соседние функции в одном файле views

upd. плохой вариант, ищу другой